# Integral of $L^1$ function composed with a flow is continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, measure-theory

Let $T_s: X \to X$ be an invertible measure preserving flow that is jointly measurable on $[0,1] \times X$ and such that $T_s$ preserves $(X,\mu)$.  Let $f \in L^1(X)$.  On page 78 of Karl Petersen's Ergodic theory book there is an implicit assumption that the function $F_t(x)=\int_0^tf(T_s(x))ds$ is continuous in $t$ with $x$ fixed.  At first glance it seems like the natural way to prove this would be to somehow make an estimate like $|F_t(x)-F_s(x)| \leq (t-s) \int_X|f| d \mu$.  The issue is that I can't really see a way to connect the Lebesgue measure $dr$ with $d \mu$.  We aren't told that the flow is absolutely continuous in time so we can't use the radon derivative, unless I missed something.  Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:  If it helps, we also assumed that the flow is ergodic on a probability space.

Comment: No continuity is mentioned in the reference you mentioned. Also, some assumptions may be missing. For example, $T$ is $\mu$-invariant or something like that, and double measurability of $T:X\times\mathbb{R}\rightarrow X$.

Comment: We have those, I 'll add them

Comment: That would be a good idea. Also, no claim of continuity is made in the reference. So you may have to either adjust your question or ask for conditions for continuity.

Comment: you need it to use the rising sun lemma on page 77.  At the top of page 78 he makes use of it.